# JAVA remove the last "*" in the string

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to remove ONLY the last * in the string. For example, `abc*` should become `abc`.  `abc*d*d` should become `abc*dd`.

I checked other solutions, I found:

```
parameter.replaceAll("a$", "b")
```

This will replace the last "a" by "b". However, when I change it to this it shows an error:

```
parameter.replaceAll("*$", "b")
```

I also tried:

```
parameter.replaceAll("\\*$", "b")
```

Comment: *I also tried: parameter.replaceAll("\\*$", "b").* And what was the result?

Comment: `parameter = parameter.replaceAll("\\*$", "b")` - did you assign the result to a variable before checking its value? See [the **online Java demo**](https://ideone.com/HPlLir), **your code works** as expected.

Comment: Illegal escape character in string literal @kaya3

Comment: What do expect the result to be of the following situations: (1) `a*bc`, (2) `a*b*c`, (3) `a*b*c*`

Comment: parameter = parameter.replaceAll("\\*$", "b") . This also doesn't work, it won't replace anything.

Comment: I did `"abc*".replaceAll("\\*$", "b")` and the result is `"abcb"`. I think you missed one of the backslashes when you tried it.

Comment: See [**Java demo**](https://ideone.com/HPlLir), your code works

Comment: "abc*".replaceAll("\\*$", "b") This doesn't work if it has 2 stars, such as `"abc*d*d".replaceAll("\\*$", "b")` is still "abc*d*d" @WiktorStribiżew . @kaya3

Answer (score 1):

```
parameter = parameter.replaceFirst("\\*$", "b");  // "aaa*" to "aaab"
parameter = parameter.replaceFirst("\\*([^*]*)$", "b$1"); // "aa*aa*aa" to "aa*aabaa"
```

Comment: Trailing `(` after the  semicolon

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a performance-heavy regex, you can use `lastIndexOf()` and `substring()`, for better performance when used inside a tight loop.

```
int idx = parameter.lastIndexOf('*');
if (idx != -1)
    parameter = parameter.substring(0, idx).concat(parameter.substring(idx + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you could use a greedy `(.+)` up to the (last occurrence of) `*` and it should remove what you want. For example:

[`(.+)\*`](https://regex101.com/r/1heQql/2) (click to see it on regex101)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
parameter.replaceAll("[*]([^*]*)$", "$1")
//                    ^^^
//                     A ^^^^^^^
//                          B
```

Match an asterisk (A) followed by 0 or more non-asterisks (B). The parentheses surrounding B mean that string is captured as `$1`. The replacement string only contains `$1`, which means that effectively, the asterisk is erased.

Make sure to assign the result to a variable, or print it. `replaceAll()` doesn't modify `parameter` in place; it returns the modified string.